# Output all names of a table in a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to display all `last_name` from my `employees` table in this procedure.

Error: `ORA-01422: Request returns more than the requested number of lines`

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE writeAllEmployees AS 
  lastn employees.last_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
 SELECT last_name INTO lastn FROM employees;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lastn);
 END;
 /
 EXEC writeAllEmployees;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are more then one rows in the table, you'll need a loop:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE writeAllEmployees AS 
BEGIN
  for cur_r in (SELECT last_name FROM employees) loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cur_r.last_name);
  end loop;
END;
/
EXEC writeAllEmployees;
```

Don't forget to enable serveroutput; in some tools that's by running `set serveroutput on`.

Comment: lastn not declared. Don't know why

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't pay attention to it. Fixed; have a look, please.